# JS - SELECT2 - Keep "parent" disabled option on search

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

**Hello,**

I'm currently attempting to use Select2 for a legacy system, where there's a need for a bunch nested options - More than the one level Select2 supports. It's being done by using disabled options as a "label" for each parent.

**Question is:** How can I keep all disabled options in the select-box no matter what I'm actually searching for in the search field? No matter what the term is, the disabled options should *not* be filtered out while still giving me the term I searched for - disabled or not.

This is currently what I've got:

```
        function customMatch(params, data) {
            // If there are no search terms, return all of the data
            if ($.trim(params.term) === '') { return data; }

            // Do not display the item if there is no 'text' property
            if (typeof data.text === 'undefined') { return null; }

            // `params.term` is the user's search term
            // `data.text` should be checked against
            var q = params.term.toLowerCase();
            if (data.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(q) > -1) {
                $.extend({}, data, true);
                return data;
            }

            // Return `null` if the term should not be displayed
            return null;                
        }

        //Init select
        $(".select2").select2({
            placeholder: "Vælg en kategori",
            debug: true,
            matcher: customMatch
        });
```